# Get Post Primary Category

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, taxonomy, html

I have troubles with getting the posts primary set category. How should I achieve this?

My code:

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'event-categories');

if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $cat_obj = get_term($term->term_id, 'event-categories');
        $cat_slug = $cat_obj->slug;
    }
}
```

and in my html

```
<div class="post_kachel <?php echo $cat_slug; ?>">
```

Comment: Anyone? If something is not clear, then please tell me - I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. 
Add this to functions.php and call it from anywhere you want.

```
function get_post_primary_category($post_id, $term='category', $return_all_categories=false){
        $return = array();

        if (class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')){
            // Show Primary category by Yoast if it is enabled & set
            $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( $term, $post_id );
            $primary_term = get_term($wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term());

            if (!is_wp_error($primary_term)){
                $return['primary_category'] = $primary_term;
            }
        }

        if (empty($return['primary_category']) || $return_all_categories){
            $categories_list = get_the_terms($post_id, $term);

            if (empty($return['primary_category']) && !empty($categories_list)){
                $return['primary_category'] = $categories_list[0];  //get the first category
            }
            if ($return_all_categories){
                $return['all_categories'] = array();

                if (!empty($categories_list)){
                    foreach($categories_list as &$category){
                        $return['all_categories'][] = $category->term_id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: You should add a description what do the function and how it is possible to use that inside the template files.

Comment: I have mentioned that this function should include inside the functions.php and possible to access from anywhere

Comment: yep, but anywhere is not a good helping for starters, especially in the theme context.